# Why does the server log that it can not open keystore.jks when I try to create a connection pool?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, connection, glassfish, connection-pooling

Why am I not able to create a JDBC Connection Pool in GlassFish 5.0? I want connect to MySQL server. I created connection pool by guide, but nothing is working.

I used Resource type: `java.sql.DataSource`
Driver class name: `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource`

> [2018-07-17T15:45:15.500+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING]
>   [test.connection.pool.failed
>   [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service]
>   [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis:
>   1531831515500] [levelValue: 900] [[   RAR8054: Exception while
>   creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ pool ], Connection
>   could not be allocated because: Cannot open
>   file:/Library/glassfish5.0/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks
>   [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]]]

Answer (score 0):

The keystore.jks is needed for creating secure connections. The error looks like the keystore password does not match GlassFish's master password (which is, by default, `changeit`).

Without knowing a lot more about the environment, it may be best to begin again with a new domain. Debugging this kind of exception to find the problem and fix it would be very difficult through StackOverflow.

Before you delete your current domain, however, it would be a good idea to create a brand new GlassFish domain and try to create the connection pool before doing anything else, just to make sure that starting fresh will indeed solve the problem. If it does, then you can proceed with making the changes needed to run your app on GlassFish.

Comment: This is a no-solution. There has to be an easy way o fix this without re-creating a domain. This is not an option in many situations.