# Cannot open file:E:\glassfish-5.1.0\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]

Tags: java, glassfish

When I run a JDBC web application using eclipse glassfish and servlets I got this message.

> Cannot open
>   file:E:\glassfish-5.1.0\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks
>   [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]

please help me to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381969/why-does-the-server-log-that-it-can-not-open-keystore-jks-when-i-try-to-create-a?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I added this : ?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false on jdbcUrl. so the full link is:
 jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false

Now it's working successfully